# Changing the Parallels menubar icon?

Tags: operating-systems, icons, xorg, parallels

Is it possible to change the Parallels menubar icon from the red icon to a black and white version?

I already know how to change the actual dock icons, but I'd like all the menubar icons to be a uniform color.  I know it's purely aesthetic, but I prefer it.